# Getting an Apex CPU Time limit exceeded error

Tags: apex, trigger, loop

I have `Opportunity` parent to `Budget Allocation`. When I enter `Budget Amount` and select a `Start Date` and `End Date` on an `Opportunity` record insert it, a `Budget Allocation` record should be created with its `Monthly Budget` and `Number of Days`. All code is working for a single record but for bulk updates I get an Apex CPU Time limit exception.

I am using a query in the `updateChild` method. How can I remove my query in a for loop?

Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class InsertBudgetOpp {

    public string getMonth(Integer monthNumber) {
        Map < Integer, String > monthMap = new Map < Integer, String > ();
        monthMap.put(1, '01 January');
        monthMap.put(2, '02 February');
        monthMap.put(3, '03 March');
        monthMap.put(4, '04 April');
        monthMap.put(5, '05 May');
        monthMap.put(6, '06 June');
        monthMap.put(7, '07 July');
        monthMap.put(8, '08 August');
        monthMap.put(9, '09 September');
        monthMap.put(10, '10 October');
        monthMap.put(11, '11 November');
        monthMap.put(12, '12 December');
        return monthMap.get(monthNumber);
    }

    public List<Budget_Allocation__c> insertChild(String oppId, Date startDate, Date endDate, Integer tb) {

        Integer startDay = startDate.day();
        Integer startMonth = startDate.month();
        Integer startYear = startDate.year();

        Integer endDay = endDate.day();
        Integer endMonth = endDate.month();
        Integer endYear = endDate.year();

        Decimal totalBudget = tb;
        Decimal numberDays = startDate.daysBetween(endDate);
        Decimal perDayBudget = totalBudget / numberDays;
        Integer numberOfMonths = startDate.monthsBetween(endDate) + 1;

        Integer numberOfYear = endYear - startYear + 1;
        String stringMonth;

        //System.debug('oppId==> ' + oppId);
        //System.debug('startDate==> ' + startDate);
        //System.debug('endDate==> ' + endDate);
        //System.debug('startDate==> ' + startDate);
        //System.debug('totalBudget==> ' + totalBudget);
        //System.debug('numberDays==> ' + numberDays);
        //System.debug('perDayBudget==> ' + perDayBudget);

        InsertBudgetOpp monthString = new InsertBudgetOpp();

        Integer counterMonth = startMonth;
        Integer counterYear = startYear;
        Integer startOnce = 0;
        Integer daysPerMonth;
        List < Budget_Allocation__c > baList = new List < Budget_Allocation__c > ();
        //system.debug('--baList--'+baList);
        Budget_Allocation__c ba = new Budget_Allocation__c();

        If(startMonth == endMonth  && startYear == endYear ){
        //System.debug('>>>>>>>single month');
            ba.Opportunity1__c = oppId;
            ba.Budget_of__c = startYear + ' ' + monthString.getMonth(startMonth );
            // ba.Budget_Month__c = stringMonth;
            ba.Budget__c = totalBudget;
            ba.No_of_Days__c = endDay - startDay + 1 ;
            ba.Opportunity_Flag__c=true;
            baList.add(ba);
            //system.debug('--baList--'+baList);
        }else{
            //System.debug('>>>>>> Multiple month==> ');
        for (Integer i = 0; i < numberOfMonths; i++) {
            ba = new Budget_Allocation__c();
            stringMonth = monthString.getMonth(counterMonth);
            daysPerMonth = Date.daysInMonth(counterYear, counterMonth);

            if (counterMonth == startMonth && startOnce == 0) {
                ba.Opportunity1__c = oppId;
                ba.Budget_of__c = counterYear + ' ' + stringMonth;
                // ba.Budget_Month__c = stringMonth;
                ba.Budget__c = perDayBudget * (daysPerMonth - startDay);
                ba.No_of_Days__c = daysPerMonth - startDay + 1;
                ba.Opportunity_Flag__c=true;
            } else if (i == numberOfMonths - 1) {
                ba.Opportunity1__c = oppId;
                ba.Budget_of__c = counterYear + ' ' + stringMonth;
                // ba.Budget_Month__c = stringMonth;
                ba.Budget__c = perDayBudget * (endDay);
                ba.No_of_Days__c = endDay;
                ba.Opportunity_Flag__c=true;
            } else {
                ba.Opportunity1__c = oppId;
                ba.Budget_of__c = counterYear + ' ' + stringMonth ;
                //ba.Budget_Month__c = stringMonth;
                ba.Budget__c = perDayBudget * daysPerMonth;
                ba.No_of_Days__c = daysPerMonth;
                ba.Opportunity_Flag__c=true;
            }
            baList.add(ba);
            //system.debug('--baList--'+baList);
            counterMonth++;
            if (counterMonth > 12) {
                counterMonth = 1;
                startOnce =1;
                counterYear++;
            }
        }
        }

        return baList;
        //system.debug('--baList--'+baList);      
    }

    public Map < String, Budget_Allocation__c > updateChild(String oppId, Date startDate, Date endDate, Integer totalBudget) {

        List < Budget_Allocation__c > baOldList = [select Opportunity1__c, Budget_of__c, Budget__c, No_of_Days__c from Budget_Allocation__c where Opportunity1__c = : oppId AND Opportunity_Flag__c=true  ];

        InsertBudgetOpp insertRec = new InsertBudgetOpp();
        List < Budget_Allocation__c > baNewList = insertRec.insertChild(oppId, startDate, endDate, totalBudget);
        //system.debug('--oppId--'+oppId);
        Map < String, Budget_Allocation__c > baOldMap = new Map < String, Budget_Allocation__c > ();
        Map < String, Budget_Allocation__c > baNewMap = new Map < String, Budget_Allocation__c > ();

        Set < String > baNames = new Set < String > ();
        for (Budget_Allocation__c o: baOldList) {
            baOldMap.put(o.Budget_of__c, o);
        }

        for (Budget_Allocation__c o: baNewList) {
            baNewMap.put(o.Budget_of__c, o);
        }
        //System.debug('Map of Old Values ==> ' + baOldMap);
        //System.debug('Map of New Values ==> ' + baNewMap);
        String s1;
        String s2;
        for (String old: baNewMap.keySet()) {
            if (baOldMap.containsKey(old)) {
                baNewMap.get(old).Id = baOldMap.get(old).Id;
                baNames.add(baNewMap.get(old).Budget_of__c);
            }
        }
        //System.debug('Names To be removed ==> ' + baNames);
        baOldMap.keySet().removeAll(baNames);
        //System.debug('Map of Old Values ==> ' + baOldMap);
        delete baOldMap.values();
        //System.debug('Map of New Values ==> ' + baNewMap);

        return baNewMap;   
    }
}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger EstimateBudgetPerMonth on Opportunity__c(after insert, after update) {

    Map<Id, Date> startDate =new Map<Id, Date>();
    Map<Id, Date> endDate = new Map<Id, Date>();
    Map<Id, Integer > totalBudget= new Map<Id, Integer >();
    Set < Id > oppId = new Set < Id > ();
    List < Budget_Allocation__c > baNewList =new List < Budget_Allocation__c >();
    List < Budget_Allocation__c > baNewList1 =new List < Budget_Allocation__c >();
    Integer isChanged=0;
   // Integer totalBudget;
   if(checkRecursive.runOnce())
    {
    for (Opportunity__c opp: Trigger.new) 
    {
        startDate.put(opp.Id,opp.Campaign_Start_Date1__c);
        endDate.put(opp.Id,opp.Campaign_End_Date1__c);
        totalBudget.put(opp.Id, Integer.valueOf(opp.Budget1__c));
        //startDate = opp.Campaign_Start_Date1__c;
        //endDate = opp.Campaign_End_Date1__c;
       // totalBudget = Integer.valueOf(opp.Budget1__c);

        oppId.add(opp.Id);

        //system.debug('--oppId--'+oppId);

       if (Trigger.isUpdate)
       {
       If( Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).Campaign_Start_Date1__c != Trigger.newMap.get(opp.Id).Campaign_Start_Date1__c){
       //System.debug('--= start date changed-');
        isChanged=1;
       }
       If( Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).Campaign_End_Date1__c != Trigger.newMap.get(opp.Id).Campaign_End_Date1__c){
       //System.debug('--===End date changed==--');
        isChanged=1;
       }
       If( Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).Budget1__c != Trigger.newMap.get(opp.Id).Budget1__c){
       //System.debug('--===Budget Changed==--');
        isChanged=1;
       }
       }

    }

    InsertBudgetOpp insertRec = new InsertBudgetOpp();
    InsertBudgetOpp updateRec = new InsertBudgetOpp();



    if (Trigger.isInsert) {
        //System.debug('--===Insert==--#--===Insert==--#--===Insert==--');
        List < Budget_Allocation__c > baList =new List < Budget_Allocation__c >();
        //List < Budget_Allocation__c > baNewList =new List < Budget_Allocation__c >();
        Map<Id,Budget_Allocation__c > baAllMap= new Map<Id,Budget_Allocation__c >();
        for(Id id: oppId){
             baList =new List < Budget_Allocation__c >();
             baList  = insertRec.insertChild(id , startDate.get(id), endDate.get(id), totalBudget.get(id));
             //system.debug('--baList--'+baList);
             baNewList.addall(baList);

        }



    } else if (Trigger.isUpdate && isChanged==1) {
        //System.debug('--===Update==--#--===Update==--#--===Update==--');
        //

       Map < String, Budget_Allocation__c > baNewMap  =new Map < String, Budget_Allocation__c >();
       for(Id id: oppId){
        baNewMap = updateRec.updateChild(id , startDate.get(id), endDate.get(id), totalBudget.get(id));
        //system.debug('--===baNewMap==--'+baNewMap);
        baNewList1.addAll(baNewMap.values());
        }

    }
    try {
        insert  baNewList;
        upsert baNewList1;
    } catch(DmlException e) {
        System.debug('----Exception : ' + e.getMessage());
    }

   }

}
```

Comment: Holy query in loops, unnecessary loops, extraneous code batman. You are going to have to do a serious review of your code and implement some best practices. For starters, never query in a loop (calling `updateChild`). Also, define your final maps once (getMonth()) instead of executing the method each and every time, property that never change but are in a method that gets called many times, define them once, not with each method call. This will require some serious work to simplify and is a bit too broad for this venue

Comment: If I have time tomorrow I will take a look at this if no-one else has been generous enough with their time. In the meantime, give it a go and see what you can come up with. Put your mind into the frame of everything you do takes CPU time. If something does not change, do not build it every time you want to get it. If I wanted to look out a window I would not want to have to put in a new window each and every time. Sorry, tired and rambling but you get the point

Answer (score 3):

As Eric mentioned, your code right now is extremely messy. Some collection variables are getting initialized multiple times, others don't serve much purpose at all, some variables are never used, some variables that never change are being constantly re-declared, and the overall structure looks to be a bit wobbly.

There were a few things that came to mind while I was digesting your code.

- In your class `InsertBudgetOpp`, you aren't really taking advantage of what classes can do.
- There are some places which could better adhere to DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principles
- There doesn't appear to be any reason why you need to send each opp into the `InsertBudgetOpp` class separately

  - put another way, there doesn't appear to be a reason why you shouldn't pass trigger.new into a class constructor

I'll start with overhauling `InsertBudgetOpp`. In my example, I've renamed this class as `BudgetOppHelper`. It's a minor thing, but it describes what the class actually does at least a little better

```
public with sharing class BudgetOppHelper {
    private static Map < Integer, String > monthMap = new Map < Integer, String > {
        1 => '01 January',
        2 => '02 February',
        3 => '03 March',
        4 => '04 April',
        5 => '05 May',
        6 => '06 June',
        7 => '07 July',
        8 => '08 August',
        9 => '09 September',
        10 => '10 October',
        11 => '11 November',
        12 => '12 December'
    };

    private List<Budget_Allocation__c> budgetAllocationList;
    private Map<Id, Opportunity__c> oppMap;
    private Map<Id, Integer> oppToNumMonths;
    private Map<Id, Opportunity__c> changedOpps;

    public BudgetOppHelper(Map<Id, Opportunity__c> incomingOppMap){
        oppMap = incomingOppMap == null ? new Map<Id, Opportunity__c>() : incomingOppMap;

        changedOpps = new Map<Id, Opportunity__c>();
        budgetAllocationList = new List<Budget_Allocation__c>();

        oppToNumMonths = new Map<Id, Integer>();

        populateNumMonths();
    }

    public BudgetOppHelper(Map<Id, Opportunity__c> incomingOppMap, Map<Id, Opportunity__c> changedOppMap){
        changedOpps = changedOppMap == null ? new Map<Id, Opportunity__c>() : changedOppMap;

        oppMap = incomingOppMap == null ? new Map<Id, Opportunity__c>() : incomingOppMap;
        oppMap.keySet().remove(changedOppMap.keySet());

        budgetAllocationList = new List<Budget_Allocation__c>();

        oppToNumMonths = new Map<Id, Integer>();

        populateNumMonths();
    }


    public List<Budget_Allocation__c> run(){
        List<Budget_Allocation__c> result;
        result = createBudgetAllocations(oppMap);

        if(changedOpps.size() > 0){
            result.addAll(updateBudgetAllocations(changedOpps));
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void populateNumMonths(){
        for(Opportunity__c opp : oppMap.values){
            oppToNumMonths.put(opp.Id, opp.Campaign_Start_Date1__c.monthsBetween(opp.Campaign_End_Date1__c) + 1);
        }
    }

    private List<Budget_Allocation__c> createBudgetAllocations(Map<Id, Opportunity__c> oppsForWork){
        List<Budget_Allocation__c> newAllocations = new List<Budget_Allocation__c>();

        Integer numberOfMonths = 0;
        Integer perDayBudget = 0;

        Integer startDay;
        Integer startMonth;
        Integer startYear;

        // endMonth and endYear are never used, so they have been removed
        Integer endDay;

        Integer currentYear;
        Integer currentMonth;

        Budget_Allocation__c workingAllocation;

        for(Opportunity__c opp : oppSet){
            numberOfMonths = oppToNumMonths.get(opp.Id);
            perDayBudget = opp.Budget1__c / opp.Campaign_Start_Date1__c.daysBetween(Campaign_End_Date1__c);

            startDay = opp.Campaign_Start_Date1__c.day();
            startMonth = opp.Campaign_Start_Date1__c.month();
            startYear = opp.Campaign_Start_Date1__c.year();

            endDay = opp.Campaign_End_Date1__c.day();

            currentYear = startYear;
            currentMonth = startMonth;

            Budget_Allocation__c baseAllocation = new Budget_Allocation__c(
                Opportunity1__c = opp.Id,
                Opportunity_Flag__c = true
            );

            for(Integer i = 1; i <= numberOfMonths; i++){
                if(currentMonth > 12){
                    currentMonth = 1;
                    currentYear++;
                }

                Integer daysInMonth = Date.daysInMonth(currentYear, currentMonth);

                workingAllocation = baseAllocation.clone(false, true, false, false);
                workingAllocation.Budget_of__c = currentYear + ' ' + monthMap.get(currentMonth);

                if(i == 1){
                    if(numberOfMonths == 1){
                        workingAllocation.Budget__c = opp.Budget1__c;
                    } else {
                        workingAllocation.Budget__c = perDayBudget * (daysInMonth - startDate + 1);
                    }

                    workingAllocation.No_of_Days__c = daysInMonth - startDay + 1;
                } else if(i == numberOfMonths){
                    workingAllocation.Budget__c = perDayBudget * (endDay);                  
                    workingAllocation.No_of_Days__c = endDay;
                } else {
                    workingAllocation.Budget__c = perDayBudget * daysInMonth;
                    workingAllocation.No_of_Days__c = daysInMonth;
                }

                newAllocations.add(workingAllocation);
                currentMonth++;
            }
        }

        return newAllocations;
    }

    private List<Budget_Allocation__c> updateBudgetAllocations(Map<Id, Opportunity__c> oppsForWork){
        List<Budget_Allocation__c> newAllocations = new List<Budget_Allocation__c>();
        delete [SELECT Id FROM Budget_Allocation__c WHERE Opportunity1__c IN :oppsForWork.keySet()];
        newAllocations = createBudgetAllocations(oppsForWork);

        return newAllocations;
    }
}
```

Now some explanation for what I've done

- Since `monthMap` will never change, it's a good idea to make this a static class variable. By doing this, you save the cost of re-creating the map every time that your `getMonth()` would otherwise be called
- By storing the Opportunities from your trigger in some class variables, we remove the need to construct individual maps to store the start date, end date, and total budget. This also aids in separation of concerns (your trigger doesn't have any use for these maps, outside of passing them in to your existing methods)
- Separating the class's public interface (`run()`) from its implementation (`createBudgetAllocations()` and `updateBudgetAllocations()`) helps make your trigger simpler
- In `createBudgetAllocations()`, I generalized the calculation of `No_of_Days__c` and `Budget__c` so it could handle the single month case along with all of your other cases. Unlikely to save much time, but this is more DRY, meaning it'll be easier to maintain.
- In `createBudgetAllocations()`, I managed to pull setting `Opportunity1__c`, and `Opportunity_Flag__c` out of the inner for loop, and `Budget_of__c1` out of the if/else logic. Setting values as early as possible (i.e. outside of as many for loop as you can) will save some time. Cloning the `baseAllocation` variable inside the inner for loop may or may not save time compared to creating a new instance
- Even though `createBudgetAllocation()` and `updateBudgetAllocation()` have access to class variables, passing parameters to these methods allows a bit more flexibility, which is key for how I set up `updateBudgetAllocation()` to work

`updateBudgetAllocations()` is a bit harder to work out. A change to the start date, end date, or budget (any of them) will require, at the very least, the budget to be re-calcuated on all `Budget_Allocation__c` records associated to the changed Opportunity. At worst, your start and end dates would shift outside of the entire original date range, rendering all of the existing `Budget_Allocation__c` records useless.

You could spend cpu time trying to figure out which records you could keep, but honestly, I don't think it's worth the cpu time, nor the time to develop. The majority of the work being done would need to be re-done even if you could re-use some records. With the other improvements made, you may find it takes less time to simply delete the existing `Budget_Allocation__c` records, and re-create them all (it'd certainly make the logic for this method simpler). This is something that you should measure for yourself.

With the above changes, your trigger would change to be this

```
trigger EstimateBudgetPerMonth on Opportunity__c(after insert, after update) {
    List<Budget_Allocation__c> budgetAllocations = new List<Budget_Allocation__c>();
    Map<Id, Opportunity__c> changedOpps = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();

    if(checkRecursive.runOnce())
    {
        for (Opportunity__c opp: Trigger.new) 
        {
            if (Trigger.isUpdate)
            {
                if( Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).Campaign_Start_Date1__c != Trigger.newMap.get(opp.Id).Campaign_Start_Date1__c
                    || Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).Campaign_End_Date1__c != Trigger.newMap.get(opp.Id).Campaign_End_Date1__c
                    || Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).Budget1__c != Trigger.newMap.get(opp.Id).Budget1__c
                )
                {
                    //System.debug('--= start date changed-');
                    changedOpps.put(opp.Id, opp);
                }
            }
        }

        BudgetOppHelper BOH = new BudgetOppHelper(trigger.newMap, changedOpps);
        budgetAllocations = BOH.run();

        try {
        upsert budgetAllocations;
        } catch(DmlException e) {
        System.debug('----Exception : ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

There's still probably room for improvement, but this will hopefully set you down the right path.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to work out an alternate solution. This is the next step I was hoping the OP would get to. At the Very least this thread is an exercise is how not to write code and the trouble it causes to refactor when it would have been easier to start with a solid design....

Answer (score 2):

Ok. This is not optimal I am sure. I did not spend time refactoring everything into the best optimized form. Also, the date functions in the code may need to be put back into their own variables depending on the amount of optimization needed after this.

I believe I followed what you are doing but I lack the insight into the business purpose and the object model so what I did was strictly based on what you had in the code.

Use this as a starting point, test it out, debug it and see if it gets you over the hump.

**Note** This type of trigger / class requires a lot of thought and effort to bring it to the most optomized form.

With that said, here is a stab:

**Trigger**

```
trigger EstimateBudgetPerMonth on Opportunity__c(after insert, after update) {

    Map<Id, Date> startDate =new Map<Id, Date>();
    Map<Id, Date> endDate = new Map<Id, Date>();
    Map<Id, Integer > totalBudget= new Map<Id, Integer >();
    Set < Id > oppId = new Set < Id > ();
    List < Budget_Allocation__c > baNewList =new List < Budget_Allocation__c >();
    List < Budget_Allocation__c > baNewList1 =new List < Budget_Allocation__c >();
    Integer isChanged=0;
   // Integer totalBudget;
   if(checkRecursive.runOnce())
    {
    for (Opportunity__c opp: Trigger.new) 
    {
        startDate.put(opp.Id,opp.Campaign_Start_Date1__c);
        endDate.put(opp.Id,opp.Campaign_End_Date1__c);
        totalBudget.put(opp.Id, Integer.valueOf(opp.Budget1__c));

        oppId.add(opp.Id);

        //system.debug('--oppId--'+oppId);

       if (Trigger.isUpdate)
       {
       If( Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).Campaign_Start_Date1__c != Trigger.newMap.get(opp.Id).Campaign_Start_Date1__c){
       //System.debug('--= start date changed-');
        isChanged=1;
       }
       If( Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).Campaign_End_Date1__c != Trigger.newMap.get(opp.Id).Campaign_End_Date1__c){
       //System.debug('--===End date changed==--');
        isChanged=1;
       }
       If( Trigger.oldMap.get(opp.Id).Budget1__c != Trigger.newMap.get(opp.Id).Budget1__c){
       //System.debug('--===Budget Changed==--');
        isChanged=1;
       }
       }

    }

    InsertBudgetOpp ibo = new InsertBudgetOpp(oppId,startdate,endDate,totalBudget);


    if (Trigger.isInsert) {
        //System.debug('--===Insert==--#--===Insert==--#--===Insert==--');
        Map<ID,Budget_Allocation__c[]> results = ibo.insertChild();

        for(Budget_Allocation__c recs: results.values()){
            baNewList.addAll(recs);
        }



    } else if (Trigger.isUpdate && isChanged==1) {
        //System.debug('--===Update==--#--===Update==--#--===Update==--');
        //

        Map<ID,Map < String, Budget_Allocation__c >> results = ibo.updateChild();

        for(Id id: oppId){
            for(Budget_Allocation__c[] recs : results.get(oppId).values()){
                baNewList1.addAll(recs);
            }
        }

    }

    try {
        insert  baNewList;
        upsert baNewList1;
    } catch(DmlException e) {
        System.debug('----Exception : ' + e.getMessage());
    }

   }

}
```

**Class**

```
public with sharing class InsertBudgetOpp {

    public static Map <Integer, String> monthMap = new Map < Integer, String >{
        1=>'01 January',
        2=>'02 February',
        3=>'03 March',
        4=>'04 April',
        5=>'05 May',
        6=>'06 June',
        7=>'07 July',
        8=>'08 August',
        9=>'09 September',
        10=> '10 October',
        11=> '11 November',
        12=> '12 December'
    };

    public Set<ID> oppIds;
    public Map<ID,Date> startDates;
    public Map<ID,Date> endDates;
    public Map<ID,Integer> totalBudgets;

    public InsertBudgetOpp(Set<ID> o, Map<ID,Date> sd, Map<ID,Date> ed, Map<ID,Integer> tb){
        oppIds = o;
        startDates = sd;
        endDates = ed;
        totalBudgets = tb;
    }

    public Map<ID,Budget_Allocation__c[]> insertChild() {

        Map < ID, Budget_Allocation__c[] > baMap = new Map < ID, Budget_Allocation__c[] > ();


        for(ID oppId : oppIds){

            Date startDate = startDates.get(oppId);
            Date endDate = endDates.get(oppid);

            Budget_Allocation__c[] baList = baMap.get(oppId);
            if(baList == null) baList = New Budget_Allocation__c[]{};

            //Need to add null checks

            Decimal totalBudget = totalBudgets.get(oppId);

            Decimal perDayBudget = totalBudget / startDate.daysBetween(endDate);
            Integer numberOfMonths = startDate.monthsBetween(endDate) + 1;

            Integer daysPerMonth;
            //system.debug('--baList--'+baList);


            If(startdate.month() == enddate.month()  && startdate.year() == enddate.year() ){
            //System.debug('>>>>>>>single month');
                Budget_Allocation__c ba = new Budget_Allocation__c(
                    Opportunity1__c = oppId,
                    Budget_of__c = counterDate.year() + ' ' + monthMap.get(counterDate.month()),
                    ba.Budget__c = totalBudget,
                    ba.No_of_Days__c = endDate.day() - startDate.day() + 1,
                    ba.Opportunity_Flag__c=true
                );
                baList.add(ba);
                //system.debug('--baList--'+baList);
            }else{
                //System.debug('>>>>>> Multiple month==> ');
                for (Integer i = 0; i < numberOfMonths; i++) {
                    Date counterDate = startDate.addMonths(i);
                    daysPerMonth = Date.daysInMonth(counterDate.year(), counterDate.month());

                    Budget_Allocation__c ba = new Budget_Allocation__c(
                        ba.Opportunity1__c = oppId,
                        ba.Budget_of__c = counterDate.year() + ' ' + monthMap.get(counterDate.month()),
                        ba.Opportunity_Flag__c=true
                    );

                    if (counterDate.month() == startDate.month()) {
                        ba.Budget__c = perDayBudget * (daysPerMonth - startDate.day());
                        ba.No_of_Days__c = daysPerMonth - startDate.day() + 1;
                    } else if (i == numberOfMonths - 1) {
                        ba.Budget__c = perDayBudget * (endDate.day());
                        ba.No_of_Days__c = endDate.day();
                    } else {
                        ba.Budget__c = perDayBudget * daysPerMonth;
                        ba.No_of_Days__c = daysPerMonth;
                    }

                    baList.add(ba);
                    //system.debug('--baList--'+baList);
                }
            }
            baMap.put(oppId,baList);
        }
        return baMap;
        //system.debug('--baList--'+baList);      
    }

    public Map<ID,Map < String, Budget_Allocation__c >> updateChild() {

        List < Budget_Allocation__c > baOldList = [select Opportunity1__c, Budget_of__c, Budget__c, No_of_Days__c from Budget_Allocation__c where Opportunity1__c IN : oppIds AND Opportunity_Flag__c=true  ];
        List < Budget_Allocation__c > baToDel = New List < Budget_Allocation__c >();

        Map< ID, Budget_Allocation__c[] > baNewChildMap = insertChild();
        //system.debug('--oppId--'+oppId);
        Map<ID,Map < String, Budget_Allocation__c >> baOldMap = new Map<ID,Map < String, Budget_Allocation__c >> ();
        Map<ID,Map < String, Budget_Allocation__c >> baNewMap = new Map<ID,Map < String, Budget_Allocation__c >> ();

        Set < String > baNames = new Set < String > ();

        for (Budget_Allocation__c o: baOldList) {
            if(!baOldMap.containsKey(o.Opportunity1__c)){
                baOldMap.put(o.Opportunity1__c,new Map<String,Budget_Allocation__c>());
            }

            baOldMap.get(o.Opportunity1__c).put(o.Budget_of__c, o);
        }

        for (Budget_Allocation__c o: baNewList) {
            if(!baNewMap.containsKey(o.Opportunity1__c)){
                baNewMap.put(o.Opportunity1__c,new Map<String,Budget_Allocation__c>());
            }

            baNewMap.get(o.Opportunity1__c).put(o.Budget_of__c, o);

        }
        //System.debug('Map of Old Values ==> ' + baOldMap);
        //System.debug('Map of New Values ==> ' + baNewMap);
        for(ID oppId : oppIds){
            oppBaNewMap = baNewMap.get(oppId);
            oppBaOldMap = baOldMap.get(oppId);

            for (String old: oppBaNewMap.keySet()) {
                if (oppBaOldMap.containsKey(old)) {
                    oppBaNewMap.get(old).Id = oppBaOldMap.get(old).Id;
                    baNames.add(oppBaNewMap.get(old).Budget_of__c);
                }
            }
            //System.debug('Names To be removed ==> ' + baNames);
            oppBaOldMap.keySet().removeAll(baNames);
            //System.debug('Map of Old Values ==> ' + baOldMap);
            baToDel.addAll(baOldMap.values());
            //System.debug('Map of New Values ==> ' + baNewMap);
        }

        delete baToDel;
        return baNewMap;   
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 from me for martyring yourself on this one; even leaving in the `isChanged` variable as an integer

Comment: @crop1645 - lol. Yea, there is a lot left to do - Including a complete redesign..but I did not have time to go there yet